# Which Hadiths relate the story of the Satanic Verses incident?

Tags: quran, aqidah, revelation, quranic-events

I did some superficial googling on the subject and I found that the transmissions of the story of the satanic verses incident is considered "weak" so this must mean there are some documented Hadiths about them. Can somebody provide me with the references of as many different hadiths that speak about this incident as possible?

As wherever I looked, nobody who mentioned it on an article, YouTube video or book would ever give hadith references for the incident and I myself could not find any on the translated books on Sunnah.com and navigating the untranslated Hadith books is difficult for me, although not impossible.

Please give references to hadiths that relate the satanic verses incident regardless if its in Arabic or not.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the story of idols in Surah Annajem (the star), that was not weak but instead fabricated, and even the Ayah that states that every prophet will get some satanic influence during reciting Ayat, its meaning is very different in arabic. if you understand arabic please check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHjt0t8MYPk